# How to check if timestamp of SQL fetched dateTime object is older than another one with moment.JS?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I query a dateTime object from PostgreSQL DB using an AJAX call which returns the following format:

```
2019-12-13T22:59:59Z // print type of: `undefined`
```

I now want to compare the timestamp of that object with the current time `now` and fire a function if the timestamp is not older than 5 seconds compared to the current time.

My idea is to calculate the difference in seconds and check the result for <> 5.

But how can I convert the database fetched dateTime object into a `moment` object to be able to compare them?

**Edit:**

Due to the conclusions from the comments provided, I changed my logic and end up with the following problem:

I have a timestamp in SQL which changes secondly. I fetch this timestamp with AJAX and would like to fire a function if the new timestamp is not older than 5 seconds than the previous one.

I set up `moment.js` objects to calculate the difference. Now my problem is that on the first iteration `latestTick` is not defined.

How can i design the loop that it compares both timestamps and always updates the `latestTick` with the `lastTick` for the next iteration (and also won't error on the first iteration)?

**Javascript:**

```
Ajax call...
[...]
lastTick = response[0].fields.account_lastTick.toString()
                lastTick1 = lastTick.slice(0, 10)
                lastTick2 = lastTick.slice(11, 19)
                lastTick = lastTick1 + ' ' + lastTick2
                lastTick = moment(lastTick, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')

                if ((lastTick.diff(latestTick, 'seconds')) != 0) {
                   console.log('not Zero')

                } else {
                    console.log('Zero')
                }                
                latestTick = moment(lastTick, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
[...]
```

Comment: [Parse the date.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Also note that what you want to do inherently assumes that the client clock is "correct" (for some meaning of the term).  You don't control it, so you really can't know what the time difference means.

Comment: @Pointy we can know the time difference if we have timezone or unix timestamp.

Comment: @PakpoomTiwakornkit yes, but presumably the comparison code is running in the *client browser*.  How accurate is the clock? Is it deliberately or accidentally seconds or minutes off of actual time?

Comment: guys I made an edit due to the fact that my problem has changed considering your comments.

Comment: @Pointy If the code is run on client then we need to rely on client-side clock and timezone. Also HTTPS handshake is done based on client datetime and timezone (and compare the datetime on server).

Comment: Well I really think that this work is better done on the server, possibly in Postgresql itself.  Then there's only one clock involved.

Comment: @Pointy yes I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea on how to compare time in Moment.js. you can do this

```
import moment from "moment"
const dateTimeStr = "2019-12-13T22:59:59Z" // your DB already includes timezone in the response (UTC+00:00)
const dateTimeMoment = moment(dateTimeStr)
const next5MinsMoment = moment().add(5, 'minutes')

if(dateTimeMoment.isBefore(next5MinsMoment)) {
   // fire function call
}
```